# Scope of global variable inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function data(){
    var dataval = anyValue;
    var myVar = setInterval(function(){computeData()});
    function computeData(){
      //inside this function there will be computations 
      //where dataval is included
    }
 }
```

This is just an example. My problem is that when I update the value of    dataval and call the data(), the value is not updated inside the setInterval function. Unless I change the value again and call data(). But that is not even working well.

```
anyValue  = 10
```

//the computation works

//if i update it to decreasingly, anyValue = 9, 
//it still uses the value 10,

//then if i use anyValue = 8, now it uses the value 9

This is not the code I am using. But same logic. Thanks! I hope you get my question!
`

Comment: Can you post the actual code?

Comment: I couldn't replicate your problem. I did a simple dataval += 100 in the computeData() fn and set interval to be at 1000 milliseconds. dataval is increasing as expected on every second. Can you please elaborate your problem a bit more?

Comment: Provide [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: alright  i will in a minute

Comment: The behavior described sounds like you have a closure. `computeData()` is the inner function. Inner functions will remember the value of a variable at the time when the outer function (i.e. `data()`) created the inner function. So basically, in an environment with `setInterval()`, it looks as if `computeData()` is lagging behind.

Comment: yes that seems to be the logic of it. any suggesstions?

Comment: don't know why the function is not included in the code block, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move you compute data function outside `data()` and make it accept variable e.g. `computeData(object)` then pass the object that you want to through `var myVar = setInterval(function(){computeData(dataval)});`